# Run PHP with jQuery and use variable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm making a website where you can find manuals of different brands of cars.
I have a table with ID, NAME, LINK, and CATEGORY. I want that if you click the DIV with the attribute "ford", you select all from the table where category is ford. This is my code:

jQuery

```
$('div').click(function(){
    var cat = $(this).attr('category');
});
```

and the SQL:

```
$connect = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=manuals', 'root','');
$cmd = $connect -> query("SELECT * FROM `manuals` WHERE `category`='ford'");
$resultado = $cmd->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

I know that PHP is a server side language and JS not, and JS is event driven, and all the story, but what is the easiest way to achieve this? Do I need to use forms and stuff?

Sorry for bad english!

Answer (score 1):

Use an $.ajax or $.post call and pass in the variable as a post (or get) variable.

Comment: So, execute the ajax function when clicking the div, right? will try this... thanks

Answer (score 1):

U can use AJAX() to get HTTP communication with PHP in backend.
see more in [link]http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/